# Create a new column with the value of last year in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dateset that contains dates and for each date a value and specific unit the value refers to. What I need is a new column that gives me the value for that unit exactly one year ago.
I want do this in PySpark but so far i have been unsuccessful.

Example

```
Time        Unit  Value  Value_lastYear
21-12-2022  1     3      5
21-12-2021  1     5      8
21-12-2022  2     6      7
```

Anybody a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract 365 days from the timestamp like so:

```
df = df.withColumn('new_time', F.date_sub(F.col('Time'), 365))
```